# how to deploy a monorepo with turborepo to digital ocean?

Tags: javascript, deployment, digital-ocean, turborepo

I have a monorepo managed with turborepo. It has two packages: client and api inside packages/* in the root folder. I'm trying to deploy 'api' to digital ocean but when trying to deploy it comes that it fails because as I'm using turborepo and it does not generate individual yarn.lock files to each package. this is my error output

```
[2023-01-16 18:06:59] │ project does not contain a package manager lockfile
[2023-01-16 18:06:59] │ Error: package-lock.json does not exist. Please commit either a 
                 package-lock.json or yarn.lock file to your repository and try again.
[2023-01-16 18:06:59] │ ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

As I have read. turborepo generates just one yarn.lock file into the root folder but I don't know how to deploy an individual package

Comment: This is a valid question, I wonder why did someone downvote it. I can't find anything from turborepo docs, as well as from DigitalOcean about this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **Source Directory** to `/` and then use the following build command:

```
yarn build --filter=./packages/api
```